# Online Social Collaborative Event Tool/Service

Tags: events, social-networking, collaborative

Does someone knows if there is any tool on the internet that makes possible to create and share events, so people can check things like: attend to, like it, favorite it and also post their own events. Also for that you could create different types of rooms or directories for example: inside the `web design` room/directory you can post and view other users events but just related to `web design`?

This sounds very familiar to me, but I don't know if I can find a tool that can do it all.

A friend of mine which is an artist is very interested to have a room like that so she could post her events there and ask other friends to share the same room and post their own related events (becoming a network).

If anyone know about something like this it would be great if you could share it.
I've tried to search internet over it but nothing solid so far.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It would rely on mysql backing. a table for each "room", a user table, etc...then use php/ajax/jquery for the posting of events, etc...Sounds like an interesting project! On a side note, i've been waiting to use something like this: http://www.stream-hub.com/ for ages. That would make one cool website...

Answer (score 0):

I think http://upcoming.yahoo.com/ is something interesting close to what you want.